# IAR Embedded Workbench Watch Window

Tags: enums, watch, iar

In IAR Embedded Workbench the watch windows displays several columns (Expression, Value, Location, Type). I want to see the value for a given expression as the enumeration and not the actual value. Meaning...

```
ucFruit  APPLE
```

as opposed to...

```
ucFruit  0x02
```

It seems that this would be possible since I can change the value of `ucFruit` by simply typing APPLE for its value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the variable name in the watch window and select the "Default Format" option from the displayed list the the enumeration is displayed rather than the numeric value.  The numeric value is displayed if you select "Decimal" or other numeric format.

This is how it works on my EW430.

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't work for me (EWARM though I doubt that's the difference).

Comment: Silly me. In this particular instance I was declaring `unsigned char ucFruit` as opposed to `enum fruit ucFruit`. That along with your suggestion fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I have EWARM and EWAVR32 as well, but the MSP430 one just happened to be in use when I saw your question.